# Is there any way to group only syntax errors from exceptions given by oracle server?

Tags: oracle

Basically the exceptions thrown by oracle are in the form, say for example 'ORA-01756','ORA-00907' etc. I would to know if there is a way to filter out just syntax errors may be something like a list of all such ORA related errors

Comment: [Oracle Database Error Messages](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ERRMG/toc.htm)

Comment: I imagine some run-time error codes could be actually caused by a syntax error, such as parenthesis nesting or quotes, etc.  Are you looking for a reference table/list, or you want a script to grep a file ignoring certain syntax error-based errors?

Comment: I am able to group syntax errors from the exception messages thrown by MYSQL and MSSQL by catching certain keywords in the exception message such as invalid syntax or SyntaxErrorException. I am not able to classify syntax errors in case of oracle. I am considering, for example, 'ORA-01756' as a code number which describes a particular kind of error. What I basically want is the list of all such code numbers that are even closely related to syntax errors or any other better suggestions would be of great help. Thanks in advance